# Counterexample on a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Is that possible to have an example on $$\int_{-2}^2f(x)dx=4 \text{, and $f$ is an even function}$$ but $\int_0^2f(x)dx$ does not exist?

Comment: What have you tried? What are your hypotheses on $f$?

Comment: delta function?

Comment: Where did this question come from? What are your thoughts based on what you know?

Comment: Note that @Doug's suggestion, $f(x)=4\delta(x)$ with $\delta$ the Dirac delta, is a distribution and measure (and an even one to boot), but not a true function. It leaves $\int_0^2f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ undefined because some nascent deltas aren't even.

Answer (score 2):

If the integral doesn't exist on the interval $[0,2]$, the integral on the interval  $[-2,2]$ does not exist either since
$$\int_{-2}^2f(x) dx= \int_{-2}^0f(x)dx + \int_0^2f(x)dx$$

and the sum of an existing term and a non existing term yields a non existing result.